# IM Proxy settings in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, chat, instant-messaging

I'm writing a chat application for google talk using XMPP in .NET (with agsXMPP.dll library). The chat application's login fails in my office because there is a specific proxy for IM. How to explicitly specify the proxy details. Can it be done in app.config?

My gtalk settings which works fine for gtalk:
Host:improxy
Port:8085
Proxy requires authentication:false

Comment: EDIT:
I have explicitly provided the proxy details as mentioned in the answer by ArsenMkrt, but still it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This will use system default proxy

```
    <system.net>
      <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="true" />
      </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
```

and this your specify

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
   <proxy bypassonlocal="true"
          proxyaddress="http://proxy.domain.org:8888/" />
  </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
```

see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/54f3e697-cff6-4f40-b008-fc4a5478efe3) and [here](http://rumandcode.wordpress.com/2008/07/21/easy-auto-proxy-in-c-using-appconfig/)

Comment: It is not logging in. This works perfectly without proxy. 
GTalk Settings: 
Host:improxy 
Port:8085 
Proxy requires authentication:false

Comment: what error are you getting? it should work, see http://usmanshaheen.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/http-status-407-proxy-authentication-required/

Comment: The XMPP library is not throwing error. It just doesn't fire login event. I have a different proxy setting for my browser. Can it conflict with IMproxy?

Comment: I don't know to be honest, will this help? http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/issues/detail?id=43